# cumulative donation report

Tags: custom-reports

I need to find those who have donated $1000 or more in a certain time frame. How can I prepare a cumulative report for businesses or individuals that will automatically total all donations?

Answer (score 1):

Karen, check out and install @Jamie 's excellent Summary Fields extension at https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields - it will do what you want, and more.

Answer (score 0):

Karen -

Have you tried the custom search for aggregate giving?  (Search > Custom Searches, click on Contribution Aggregate.)  If the export from that search doesn't give you all the fields you need, you could put the results into a group and then export from a search of that group.

Lesley